# Using Kate & Kdiff3 as drop-in replacements for vim/emacs

Tags: xorg, gui, root, vim, kate

By default, ubuntu-minimal uses vim-tiny, and after >20 years of using vim/emacs, I am cured, and realize that despite their obvious power, the user interface itself of both editors is not designed for humans and a horrible joke.

So I would like to replace it *completely*. Preferably with Kate, Tilde and KDiff3.

Of course I already uninstalled vim-tiny, and removed the dependency for it from ubuntu-minimal; installed Tilde, Kate and KDiff3, and added scripts named `vim` and the like, to run Tilde instead, so programs that expect vim (like ubuntu-minimal) keep working.

The problem is that when a GUI is available, Kate should be run, even when I’m root and editing system files. But Kate is smart enough to know it doesn’t need to be root the entire time, but only for saving (or sometimes opening). So I cannot just run it from root. I need it to run from that user’s session, but triggered from a root script, which then only exists when kate returns to the shell in the user’s session.

In the past, I remember that various combinations of `su`, and exporting session variables to be able to access X, did let me run things in another session. But it was anything but elegant.

**So now I would like to do it cleanly. Done in a proper way. Problem is: I don’t know what that way is. Or if there even is one defined at all.**

Sure, I might have a listener in my X session, that get sent the things to open via a FIFO or the like. But on modern systems, it feels like such facilities already exist in much more general and powerful ways. (Something like policykit or whatever it was called? … Offering more fine-grained access controls too.)

Given that other people probably already fully implemented what I want here, I’d rather ask for that, than start coding a at first hackish solution on my own.

Oh, and: I know what I’m doing. I do it for a reason. If it blows up in my face, then that was my choice, and I do not need anyone from OSHA to hold my hand, to operate a spoon. ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind: You did not read my comment in its entirety, esp. the last paragraph. Your expectation of the state of expertise I’m on seem to be extremely low. I'm way past GUI, past CLI, past patching kernels and firmware code, past writing my own OS in Haskell, and back full circle to designing my own UI paradigms that are beyond such silly separations. My UI is a GUI *and* a CLI, yet not with the flaws of either. … And I just want this silly primitive Ubuntu to be a bit closer to my unfinished own OS/shell.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Well, first of all, who made you my nanny? ;) Quite condescending, to a point where you sound like a smartdevice. ;) And second of all, I don’t think you’re assuming a level from which you can judge stupidity on things at my actual operating level. (E.g. for a former iOS user, replacing the package manager would not be a good idea. For somebody literally writing his own OS, it is a normal thing to do, to transition from the OS he uses to his new one. You just mistook me for the former. Understandable default reaction, but only if one literally doesn’t even read my question fully.:)

Comment: If you know what you're doing, of course you don't need any help, so why the question?

Comment: have it your way...but asking is also stating you do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: I simply had expected people of an even higher level of competence here. Not people with so little clue that they don’t even understand where I’m coming from, mistaking me for somebody with ever less of a clue, and answering (to that) anyway. … I don’t fault you, as most questions here probably are on the “How is babby formed?” level. This is askubuntu after all. Plus, you cannot know that you do not know that you do not know, obviously. But this is another case of the Dunning-Kruger effect *really* making interaction with laypeople annoying. … Let’s just wait for an *proper* guru, OK? ;)